# Sort a column alphanumeric and numeric ascending,then need alphanumeric data top and next numeric data

Tags: excel, vba

```
col A
gsdgdf2
jhgd742   
2375832
9879872
```

after sorting

```
col A
2375832
9879872
gsdgdf2
jhgd742
```

i need VBA code to display Alphanumeric first and numeric next as follows:

```
gsdgdf2
jhgd742
2375832
9879872
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [this code](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/672611-sorting-alphanumeric-column-character-character-using-excel-visual-basic-applications.html) by selecting the column you want sorting:

```
Sub Sort_Special()
    Dim i As Long
    With Selection
        For i = 0 To 9
            .Replace What:=i, Replacement:="ZZZZZ" & i, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        Next i
        .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
        For i = 0 To 9
            .Replace What:="ZZZZZ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```